# Folium offline heatmap does not render (no errors)

Tags: python, leaflet, folium

I'm using folium with patches for offline mode, by replacing the default JS/CSS and loading from local tilesets. So far it seems to work for normal plotting.

However, using `folium.plugins.Heatmap`, I dont see a visual for the heatmap at all. It appears as a layer as I can see it in the layercontrol, but theres no actual heatmap visually.

There are **no** console errors, and ive already altered the link in the `render` method of `heat_map.py` to load from the offline `leaflet-js` file as well. Nothing works

Anyone can guide with this?

Thanks~

Example code (not including edits for offline mode)

```
import folium
from folium.plugins import HeatMap
m = folium.Map(
        location=[1.3521, 103.8198],  
        tiles='tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
        min_zoom=5, 
        max_zoom=14,
        zoom_start=6,
        control_scale=True
    )
rand_l = np.random.uniform(1.3,1.4,size=100)
rand_lon = np.random.uniform(103.63,104,size=100)
data = np.array([rand_l,rand_lon]).reshape(100,2).tolist()
HeatMap(data).add_to(folium.FeatureGroup(name='Heat Map').add_to(m))
folium.map.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(m)
m.save("test.html")
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, It's basically my own stupidity, and was tempted to delete this question but leaving it here incase it helps anyone.

The offline mode works fine. The way I was testing it was wrong. In my rush to generate mock data, I stupidly have the data in [lat,lat]...[lon,lon] pairs instead of [lat,lon] pairs

It works. Check your input data people.